# Display the OpenFeint Welcome Back message bar on a landscape view

Tags: iphone, openfeint

When my app launches in landscape mode, the OpenFeint message bar displays as if the view is a portrait view.

How can this message be set to display correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[OpenFeint setDashboardOrientation:OrientationHere];
```